# Admob status inactive

Tags: admob

My admob status is showing as inactive. However, people have downloaded my app and I have done the test ad on my mobile phone and it work.

What could be the issue here?

As discussed in an older question it takes 24 hours, but I have wait the last two days and it is still not active. I am sure publish ID is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you launch with `GADRequest.testing` set to `true` on accident?  Are you able to see production ads at all on your device?